# Validation error does not show up in grid

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have an **MVC 3 Razor Telerik grid**. When the Update for an Edit button is clicked, the proper Controller is executed and the **TryUpdateModel** statement is performed.

I purposely put in some text that I know whould casuse an error. The TryUpdateModel returns false (which is expected in this circumstance) and then executes the return View(); statement.

However, I get back a modal dialog box that says "The requested URL returned a 500 error". If I click the modal dialog and look on the grid, no validation msg appears.

If I am **not** using a Telerik grid with just input boxes, the validation msg appears fine from my DataAnnotations that reside inside my Model.

**What am I doing incorrectly?**

Here is my View:

```
@model Telerik.Web.Mvc.GridModel<YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Customer>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customer Index";
}
<h2>
    Customer Index</h2>
@(  Html.Telerik().Grid<YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Customer>(Model.Data)
      .Name("Customers")
            .DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add(o => o.CustomerID)
                                            .RouteKey("CustomerID"))
                .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Text).ImageHtmlAttributes(new { style = "margin-left:0" }))
      .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.CustomerID).Hidden(true);
                columns.Command(commands =>
                {
                    commands.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Text);
                }).Width(200).Title("Command");
                columns.Bound(o => o.Email).Width(200);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Company).Width(200);
                columns.Bound(o => o.FirstName).Width(100).Title("FName");
                columns.Bound(o => o.LastName).Width(100).Title("LName");
                columns.Bound(o => o.Address1).Width(200).Title("Addr1");
                columns.Bound(o => o.Address2).Width(100).Title("Addr2");
                columns.Bound(o => o.City).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.State).Width(40).Title("ST");
                columns.Bound(o => o.Zip).Width(60);
                //columns.Bound(o => o.HomePhone).Width(120);
                //columns.Bound(o => o.CellPhone).Width(120);
                //columns.Bound(o => o.Website).Width(100);
                //columns.Bound(o => o.IMAddress).Width(100);
                //columns.Bound(o => o.CreatedDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").ReadOnly(true).Width(120);
                //columns.Bound(o => o.UpdatedDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").ReadOnly(true).Width(120);
            }).DataBinding(dataBinding =>
                dataBinding.Ajax()
                        .Insert("_InsertAjaxEditing", "Customer")
                        .Update("_SaveAjaxEditing", "Customer"))
    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
 )
```

Here is my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [GridAction]
        public ActionResult _SaveAjaxEditing(YeagerTechWcfService.Customer customer)
        {
            CustomerValidate custValidate = new CustomerValidate();

            custValidate.CustomerID = customer.CustomerID;
            custValidate.Email = customer.Email;
            custValidate.Company = customer.Company;
            custValidate.FirstName = customer.FirstName;
            custValidate.LastName = customer.LastName;
            custValidate.Address1 = customer.Address1;
            custValidate.Address2 = customer.Address2;
            custValidate.City = customer.City;
            custValidate.State = customer.State;
            custValidate.Zip = customer.Zip;
            custValidate.HomePhone = customer.HomePhone;
            custValidate.CellPhone = customer.CellPhone;
            custValidate.Website = customer.Website;
            custValidate.IMAddress = customer.IMAddress;

            if (TryUpdateModel(custValidate))
            {
                try
                {
                    db.EditCustomer(customer);
                    TempData["ErrCode"] = "Customer successfully updated.";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    TempData["ErrCode"] = "CustErr";
                    ViewBag.Error = ex.Message;
                    return View();
                }

            }
            else
                return View();
        }
```

Comment: Could you please post the error detail

Comment: I've found out that the validation doesn't display for 2 reasons: 1) If you are using EF and are using POCO classes generated by EF via DBContext (which contains reference properties to other entities), the Model doesn't like that which is a deficiency in MVC. 2) If you are using your Model class in an N-Tier architecture within the Data tier, MVC doesn't recognize the validation either. Only case is when you have a Model on the presentation tier (in the Models folder) and does not have any referential properties in the class. This needs to be fixed in MVC ASAP.